# Where exactly do I include a custom theme file?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I created a custom theme for my app, but I don't how to use it. From the docs , I saw that it should be included in `styles.scss` file in `src` folder, but I don't have that file in my `src` folder. Instead I have `styles.css`.
This is my `angular-cli.json` file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
"name": "test"
  },
  "apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [],
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
"protractor": {
  "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
   }
  },
  "lint": [
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
},
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
},
{
  "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
}
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
   }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
"component": {}
  },
 "styles": [
       "styles.css",
        "src/new-theme.scss"
      ]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import it in your `.angular-cli.json` file in the `styles` section:

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "new-theme.scss"
      ],
```

From the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming),

> If you are using the Angular CLI, support for compiling Sass to css is
>   built-in; you only have to add a new entry to the "styles" list in
>   angular-cli.json pointing to the theme file (e.g.,
>   unicorn-app-theme.scss).

Comment: you beat me by 18 secs mate, deleting my answer

Comment: the path should be relative to `.angular-cli.json` file , right?

Comment: ok, I'm getting confused. the theme is inside `src` folder  and  `src` is at the same level as `angular-cli.json`. what would the path be?

Comment: what is your theme name ?

Comment: it's `new-theme.scss`

Comment: it says in my `angular-cli.json` file that `property styles is not allowed`

Comment: Thats not possible, show your angular-cli.json file

Comment: I added it at the question

Comment: You are adding it twice, see in your file you already have `"styles"` after `"prefix":"app"` entry, just add the new custom theme path in that

Comment: the path was wrong . just `new-theme.scss` was enough :)

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, since you had that in src folder already . I'll update in answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular cli you can add you theme css file in your .angular-cli.josn file like below.

```
  "prefix": "sd",
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    ...
    "styles.scss"
  ],
```

Its saying `scss` because the project is lesect to use scss rather css. you can change that in your cli configuration at below line

```
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way to add your theme in angular.json

```
"styles": [
   "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
   "src/styles.css"
],
```

In my case I add a theme from angular material and works for me.